# How can I add a custom class to my Windows Forms 2.0 project?

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, winforms, class

## Background

I need to add a custom class to my project in order to deserialize and work with json data in a txt file.

Here is the class:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class ListaGeneral

    <JsonProperty("Llave1")>
    Public Property Llave1 As String()

    <JsonProperty("Cola")>
    Public Property Cola As String()

    <JsonProperty("Llave2")>
    Public Property Llave2 As String()

    <JsonProperty("Llave3")>
    Public Property Llave3 As String()

    <JsonProperty("Llave4")>
    Public Property Llave4 As String()

    <JsonProperty("Llave5")>
    Public Property Llave5 As String()

    <JsonProperty("Llave6")>
    Public Property Llave6 As String()
End Class

Public Class ListaGeneralRoot

    <JsonProperty("ListaGeneral")>
    Public Property ListaGeneral As ListaGeneral()
End Class
```

When I try to add a class to my project, it prompts me to add it to the App_Code folder. After adding it and writing my class properties, I get the following error:

```
Visual Basic 9.0 does not support auto-implemented properties.
```

I tried moving my class out of the App_Code folder. It no longer showed the error, however I was not able to use my class. I tried initializing an object in my aspx file code and it just couldn't find it.

I read this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/892040/Visual-Basic-does-not-support-auto-implemented-pro) that suggested I change my Target Framework to 4.0, which I did, moved my file back to the App_Code folder, and then I got this error:

```
Attribute specifier is not a complete statement. Use a line continuation to apply the attribute to the following statement.
```

Referring to these lines:

```
<JsonProperty("Llave1")>
Public Property Llave1 As String()
```

I tried formatting the lines like this:

```
<JsonProperty("Llave1")> Public Property Llave1 As String()
```

And I got an error saying:

```
Property without a 'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifier must provide both a 'Get' and a 'Set'.
```

## Questions

How do I add getters and setters to a JsonProperty?

Has anyone faced this issue? Is this the right track?

Would changing my target framework from v2.0 to 4.0 cause any issues? First time doing this.

Keep in mind the end goal is to add the custom class referenced above to my project and be able to use it in my aspx files, in order to deserialize json text found in a txt file.

## Update

I've tried to implement @JohnPete22 's answer like this:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class ListaGeneral

    Private _llave1 As String = String.Empty

    <JsonProperty("Llave1")> Public Property LLave1 As String
        Get
            Return _llave1
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _llave1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'etc etc etc 

    Sub New()

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class ListaGeneralRoot

    Private _listageneral As ListaGeneral = Nothing

    <JsonProperty("ListaGeneral")> Public Property ListaGeneral As ListaGeneral
        Get
            If _listageneral Is Nothing Then
                _listageneral = New ListaGeneral()
            End If
            Return _listageneral
        End Get
        Set(value As ListaGeneral)
            _listageneral = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

After trying to test my file, which has already been tested in a separate console application with the same code and it works (using my original implementation of the class, mentioned in the original example),  I cannot get the following code to work:

```
Dim ReceiptsToProcess As ListaGeneralRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ListaGeneralRoot)(json)

StatusLabel.Text = ReceiptsToProcess.ListaGeneral(0).LLave1(0)
```

errors:

```
ListaGeneral has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed

LLave1 has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed
```

I've uploaded my file to dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3kasn11oerrxbuh/20210211.txt?dl=0

If you could/would test your answers.

*My initial implementation works in a console application, but it doesn't in my web app, which is the whole point to the post.

Comment: Have you tried fully declaring your properties?

Comment: Have you tried adding setters and getters like in this example https://www.dotnetperls.com/property-vbnet ?

Comment: I'm not sure about how I could do that. Each property is a json array that may contain more json arrays. How can I write the getters and setters?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking for is an example full property declaration

Comment: I included an answer (really wanted it to be a comment) with an example of a fully declared property

Comment: You should update your development environment, thus the Language version and the Framework you use. Why are you stuck in the Jurassic? Is there a good reason? BTW, you don't need to set a `<JsonProperty>` if your class Property has the same name, as in `<JsonProperty("Llave1")> Public Property LLave1 As String`. It's not *case sensitive* either. Use it to give the Property a more meaningful name or a name that is not a keyword in the Language etc..

Comment: @Jimi I'm using Visual Studio 2015. You're saying I should update to VS2019?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 doesn't use `Visual Basic 9.0`... That's, IIRC, Version 14, which of course has Auto Properties.

Comment: @Jimi The web app was given to me a few weeks ago and it was already functional. Possibly developed in VS 2008. I am using 2015. Would you recommend I download VS 2019 still? How can I update all of the features you're suggesting?

Comment: If you can use VS 2019, why not, anyway the Language version that comes with VS 2015 already has all those *features*. When you open a Project in an Environment that is newer than the Project's you're prompted to update your Project to the new version. See whether you have a `compilerOptions="/langversion:XX` hard-coded in `web.config`. See also in the `Project` Menu, if you have the Upgrade Option enabled (to VB 14). In any case, it's just a configuration matter.

Comment: I'll ask a new question since the subject has changed so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to format this Property in the comment area, so I will add it here:

```
Private _test As String = String.Empty

<JsonProperty("Test")>
Public Property Test As String
    Get
        Return _test
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _test = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Update

```
Private _testObject As TestClassObject = Nothing

Public Property TestObject As TestClassObject
    Get
        ' you could also have logic in here to see if the value is nothing...do a DB lookup, etc...
        If _testObject Is Nothing Then
            _testObject = New TestClassObject()
        End If

        Return _testObject
    End Get
    Set(value As TestClassObject)
        _testObject = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Class TestClassObject
    ' you'd have properties, methods, etc....
    Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What about the last property? How can I write that one?

Comment: Your issue has switched a bit. This post was merely a means to show how to declare full properties, as auto-implemented properties are somewhat newer compared to the environment you are working in.